# Why does this happen? C++ Error: Unable to open file D:\Animals\Animals\Debug\Animals.obj

Tags: c++

So i'm making a game (like Pokémon) and i changed some stuff and now i get :
Error: Unable to open file D:\Animals\Animals\Debug\Animals.obj. Error code = 0x80070002.Error: Could not find 'D:\Animals\Animals\Debug\Animals.obj'. Animals.exe was built with /DEBUG:FASTLINK which requires object files for debugging.

Anybody know what is going on and how to fix this?

I used Visual Studio 2019 and x86 (and x64) debug.

My code :

animal.h :

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef ANIMAL_H
    #define ANIMAL_H

using namespace std;
namespace Animals {
    class Animal {
    public:
        string name;
        int minlevel;
        int level;
        int maxlevel;
        int baseattack;
        int baseattackraise;
        int attack;
        int basedefense;
        int basedefenseraise;
        int defense;
        int basespeed;
        int basesppedraise;
        int speed;
        int basespecial;
        int basespecialraise;
        int special;
        char type;
        Animal() {
            this->name = "DOG";
            this->minlevel = 0;
            this->level = 1;
            this->maxlevel = 100;
            this->baseattack = 1;
            this->baseattackraise = 1;
            this->basedefense = 1;
            this->basedefenseraise = 1;
            this->basespecial = 1;
            this->basespecialraise = 1;
            this->basespeed = 1;
            this->basesppedraise = 1;
            this->attack = 1;
            this->defense = 1;
            this->speed = 1;
            this->special = 1;
        };
    private:
        void  printstats() {
            cout << "\t \t" << "Attack : " << this->attack << endl;
            cout << "\t \t"<<"Defense : " << this->defense << endl;
            cout << "\t \t"<<"Speed : " << this->speed << endl;
            cout <<"\t \t" << "Special : " << this->special << endl;
        };
        void raiseattack() {
            this->attack += this->baseattackraise;
        }
        void raisedefense() {
            this->defense += this->basedefenseraise ;
        }
        void raisespeed() {
            this->speed += this->basesppedraise;
        }
        void raisespecial() {
            this->special += this->basespecialraise;
        }
        void raisestats() {
            raiseattack();
            raisedefense();
            raisespeed();
            raisespecial();
        }
        void updatestats(char  type) {
            switch (type) {
            case 'l':
                raisestats();
            }
        }
    public :
        void raiselevel() {
                this->level++ ;
                this->type = 'l';
                updatestats(this->type);
                string output = "Level Up! Your " + this->name +" has reached level : ";
                cout << output << this->level << " . Its stats are now: " << endl;
                printstats();
        };
    };

}
#endif
```

Animals.cpp :

```
// Animals.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
void startgame();
void askname();
void asktype();
void giveGrassStarter();
void giveWaterStarter();
void giveFireStarter();
#include <iostream>
#include "plantee.h"
#include "wateree.h"
#include "flamee.h"
#include "animal.h"
// #include "visualanimal.h"
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
string name;

int main()
{
    using namespace Animals;
    startgame();
    return 0;
}
void startgame() {
    char answer = 'N';
    while (answer == 'N') {
        askname();
        cout << "Alright then. You're " << name << " , right?" << "(Y/N)";
        cin >> answer;
    }
    asktype();
}
void askname() {
    cout << "Welcome. Your Journey In the World Of Animals Starts here . Please input your name";
    cin >> name;
}
void asktype() {
    char type;
    cout << "Welcome " << name << " . What type do you prefer? Water ? Grass? Fire? (W/G/F)";
    cin >> type;
    switch (type) {
    case 'G':
        giveGrassStarter();
        break;
    case 'W':
        giveWaterStarter();
        break;
    case 'F':
        giveFireStarter();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Input invalid . (G for Grass , W for Water , F for Fire)";
        asktype();
    }
}

void giveGrassStarter()
{
    cout << "So you chose Plantee , the grass-type starter. Good choice";
    Plantee starter;
}

void giveWaterStarter()
{
    cout << "So you chose Wateree , the water-type starter. Good choice";
    Wateree starter;
}

void giveFireStarter()
{
    cout << "So you chose Flamee , the fire-type starter. Good choice";
    Flamee starter;
}
```

Anybody know a possible fix? I'd also like if you explained what was going on.

Comment: If anybody request the other files i have 3 others impacting the code

Comment: @ewong no sorry i don't have dlls

Comment: so it won't work

Comment: Visual Studio sometimes gets itself confused. First thing to try is to close Visual Studio, then manually delete all the intermediate files in your project folder (that is everything in the Debug folder and the .vs folder, backup before you delete of course). Then restart visual studio and try again.

Comment: In VisualStudio underthe "Build" tab you have the option the "Clean Solution", try to do that, then rebuild your solution and see if that fixes things for you, if not try to reboot you computer, i something get permission error out of nowhere where VS cannot access the solution folder, i restart and it works again

Comment: @John thx for the advice

Comment: @john thx for the advice

Comment: @armagedescu it is in the project